# How to remove a file from SVN synchronization?

Tags: eclipse, svn, synchronization

Working with Eclipse and SVN, how do I definitely remove a file from list to never synchronize it?

Comment: Are you talking about a file that's already in the repository and you don't want to modify your local changes or a file that should never be in the repository? Also: which SVN plugin for Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I'm using Subeclipse. And I'm talking about the .classpath and .project files, I don't want to commit them never.

Comment: Did you mean to write *Subclipse* (without an *e* in the middle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- right click upon file to ignore * Team -> Add to svn:ignore

**Edit** : Are you serious? Then you are not using sublicpse

[image]

Comment: There is no such option at Eclipse IDE (or, at least, I don't found it).

Comment: It sure looks like it's disabled in the screen dump as well.

Comment: I realized that it depends on the Eclipse perspective used

Comment: Perspective doesn't make a difference. The option is not available if the resource is already committed in SVN. Change to the "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective, navigate to the resource, and delete it. Then the option will be available again back in your regular perspective.